# Correct usage of Thread counting semaphores in a Producer and Consumer example

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, threadx, counting-semaphore

I'm new to Threadx and counting semaphores functionality.
I have a code as shown below (didn't compile, just as pseudo).
I have thread which produces Data and the other Thread is consuming the data.
I want to synchronize the access to shared data with counting semaphores.
Is this as shown below the correct way conceptually?

```
#include "tx_api.h"
BUFFERSIZE 10
TX_SEMAPHORE mySemaphore;

int mySharedBuffer[BUFFERSIZE];

void producer(ulong input)
{
    while(1)
    {
       tx_semaphore_get(&mySemaphore, TX_WAIT_FOREVER); /*Lock before writing to the shared data */
       for (int i = 0; i++; i<BUFFERSIZE)
       {
         int newData = rand();
         mySharedBuffer[i] = newData;
       } 
       tx_semaphore_put(&mySemaphore); /*unlock and signalize to other thread data is ready */
       
       sleep(5);
    }
}


void consumer(ulong input)
{
  while(1)
  {
    tx_semaphore_get(&mySemaphore, TX_WAIT_FOREVER); /*Lock shared data before reading from it*/
    
    for (int i = 0; i++; i<BUFFERSIZE)
    {
        int consumedata = mySharedBuffer[--i];
    }
    tx_semaphore_put(&mySemaphore); /*unlock and signalize to producer data can be written to shared data again*/
    
    /*Do something with data*/
    
     sleep(5);  
  }
}

int main()
{
  if(tx_semaphore_create(&mySemaphore,"My Semaphore", 1) != TX_SUCCESS)
  {
    return -1
  }
  
  /*Start Producer Thread*/
  
  /*Start Consumer Thread*/
  
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that you have put-put instead of get-put in the producer, this is not good. Remove the `sleep(5);` in the consumer to see the problem. You have no mechanism to wait for data to become available. The consumer repeatedly consumes that last thing that was written (if anything!) So while you do need a mutex (as you showed), that isn't sufficient.

Comment: What is `while() { ... }`?  Can you please post your actual code?

Comment: @Andrew Henle, An infinite loop. Fixed.

Comment: @ikegami Porbably true, but I hesitate to assume that's the actual code, though, given `producer()` has two calls to `tx_semaphore_put()` and none to `tx_semaphore_get()`.   What *else* may have been mistyped?

Comment: @ikegami: Oh yes, it was typo. I meant the get in the consumer. I fixed it.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, The question is about whether this approach would work. I don't know what's this "actual code" you keep talking about.

Comment: Tip: Re "*Start Consumer Thread*", You don't need three threads. You can simply call `consumer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you have put-put instead of get-put in the producer, your approach is broken.

Remove the `sleep(5);` in the consumer to make a problem obvious. You have no mechanism to wait for data to become available. The consumer repeatedly consumes that last thing that was written (if anything!)

Remove the `sleep(5);` in the producer instead to make a different problem obvious. You have no mechanism to wait for the buffer to become available. The producer will repeatedly write to the buffer regardless of whether the current value has been consumed or not. This results in data loss!

With a single producer and a single consumer, you can use a pair of semaphores to keep them in lock step.

Producer:

1. While there's data to produce,

   1. Wait for buffer_available_sem.
   2. Produce one message.
   3. Post to data_available_sem.
2. Wait for buffer_available_sem.
3. Set done to true.
4. Post to data_available_sem.

Consumer:

1. Loop.

   1. Wait for data_available_sem.
   2. If done,

      1. Break.
   3. Consume one message.
   4. Post to buffer_available_sem.

Main:

1. Init done to false.
2. Init buffer_available_sem to 1.
3. Init data_available_sem to 0.

Comment: Changed answer.

Comment: And since the OP refers specifically to counting semaphores, I observe that this approach -- which is perfectly viable -- would also work with binary semaphores.  Counting semaphores could allow the producer to get multiple units ahead of the consumer, but then you need additional synchronization.

Comment: And additional storage for the extra units/messages. /// With a single producer and a single consumer, you could forgo additional synchronization by using a circular buffer. The two existing sems would be good enough even for a multiple-message queue.